# SQL Developer: what is the reason I cannot debug or execute SP in mysql with SQL Developer?

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am querying my Mysql database with Oracle SQL Developer. The program is working perfectly when I installed mysql connector but I can not execute or debug procedures with the ide. My version is 19.1.2.247 (internal id 247.2212)

Execute menu is deactivated:

[image]

What do I need to debug with SQL Developer? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL support is provided only to help you migrate that data to Oracle.

IDE features are reserved for Oracle/PLSQL only.

MySQL Workbench is the official ide for MySQL.

Comment: can you debug using workbrench? I don't think so because I don't see the options there

Comment: i don't know, but if Oracle were to provide a mysql debugger, it'd be there, there feature list shows they have a debugger for SQL...whatever that means

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @thatjeffsmith, that feature is a problem SQL Seveloper debug only works with Oracle. For this reason I think it is part of the solution. He told me to use Workbench but I am new there and I didn't see debug menu for stored procedure...

I discovered in .Net VS2017 the capacity to debug stored procedures in mysql using Server Explorer.

I had problems to open the stored procedure. I couldn't open the stored procedure. But after investigating, I could resolve it unchecking save my password in the connection. Once having done that I could debug the stored procedure. Totally free with VS2017 Community.

[image]

I think it is the part I was looking for to resolve my problem.

I tested:

- **HeidiSQL**: so simple but I didn't like the theme used. you can't debug.
- **Toad for mysql**: until now was working with it but now they migrated to **ToadEdge**.
- **ToadEdge**: Now trial only.
- **Workbrench**: Nice solution to forget of Toad but without Debug.
- **dbForge Express**: good theme and easy to work, for me the best one, but debug is in payment products.
- **MySQL Debugger**: Windows defender didn't execute because told me it could damage my OS. Untrusted.
- **Database4**: Windows defender didn't execute because told me it could damage my OS. Untrusted.
- **Saving logs**: it is a good idea but you lose too much time configuring it and sometimes is not good to watch the solution.

My best bet is dbForge ... but I will use Server Explorer of .Net to debug my stores.

I hope this solution can help you.